# Windows 7 batch incrementing a variable in a loop not working

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, increment

I have asked **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302453/windows-7-cmd-batch-file-how-to-increment-a-variable-in-a-loop-thru-files)** question yesterday and it was closed for syntax error, although in my tests, errorlevel was registering correctly but it is besides the matter.

My problem is, an index variable I set outside a loop, is not getting incremented inside the loop such as this example:

```
set idx=0

for %%f in (P_*.txt) do (
REM do something here 
set /a idx=idx+1
)

echo %idx%
```

result is always zero, although the files matching the pattern are over 200 in the current directory.

Why ?

EDIT: As requested, a minimally reproducible example from my cmd prompt screen scrape is below

```
C:\test>dir *.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 48E0-D051

 Directory of C:\test

04/19/2020  11:58 PM                 8 p_2.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_3.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_4.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_5.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_6.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_7.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_8.txt
04/20/2020  12:00 AM                 7 p_9.txt
               8 File(s)             57 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  217,249,751,040 bytes free

C:\test>type 2.bat
@echo off
set idx=0

for %%f in (P_?.txt) do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo %%f
set /a idx=idx+1
echo %idx%
echo ------------
)

C:\test>2.bat
p_2.txt
0
------------
p_3.txt
0
------------
p_4.txt
0
------------
p_5.txt
0
------------
p_6.txt
0
------------
p_7.txt
0
------------
p_8.txt
0
------------
p_9.txt
0
------------

C:\test>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with it from what I can see.

Comment: The snippet of code that you posted does not exhibit the issue you are experiencing. If you believe that it does, please check that the script and the `P_*.txt` files are in the same directory and that `dir P_*.txt` outputs what you are expecting.

Comment: In other question, you mention `I echo the idx value in the loop it stays at zero all the time`. Inside the loop may need `set enabledelayedexpansion` to expand variables with updated values. Examples need to be [mre].

Comment: @michael_heath I have added the enabledelayedexpansion into the loop  and still the same result. Please see the screen capture in the original question.

Comment: @SomethingDark please see the output in the original question. A subset of the files I copied to a testing directory.

Comment: Thanks @MelBurslan. Move `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` up just below `@echo off` as you do not need to set that option in the `for` loop. Change `echo %idx%` to `echo !idx!` for that variable to delay expand. Try it again. View `set /?` for more help if needed.

Comment: The `set /A` command works, it does increment the value; the problem is `echo %idx%` as @michael_heath already mentioned; when you put `echo %idx%` after the loop (hence after the closing `)`) the number of matching files will be returned, unless your original code appears in another loop or code block...

Comment: Your original code should run as intended. The code t in the EDIT section does not match the original code at all and needs [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

Comment: @michael_heath Thank you for the ```!idx!``` suggestion. That worked just the way I expected and I was not aware of different indirect notation for delayed expansion. I am from the Unix side and a single $ sign at the beginning of variable is all I need and know. Thanks again.